# Obtenga un valor de retorno de procedimiento almacenado de SQL Server con EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estoy intentando recuperar un valor que retorna de un Stored Procedure en SQL Server 2019, pero al momento de obtener el valor del parámetro de salida me ocurre una excepción. Estoy trabajando con NET.Core 3.1 y EntityFrameworkCore

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Int32
```

El procedimiento que se utiliza es similar al siguiente, sin todas las validaciones para hacerlo mas legible en este ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOGIN]
    @LOGIN    VARCHAR(50),  
    @PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
    @EXIT     INT OUTPUT,
    @MENSAJE VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT USER_APP FROM USERS 
               WHERE USER_APP = @LOGIN AND PASSWORD = @PASSWORD)
    BEGIN
        SET @EXIT = 1
        SET MENSAJE = '1'
        RETURN @EXIT
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT USER_DESK FROM USERS_DESK
               WHERE USER_DESK = @LOGIN AND PASSWORD = @PASSWORD)
    BEGIN
        SET @EXIT = 0
        SET MENSAJE = '0'
        RETURN @EXIT
    END

    SET @EXIT = 0
    RETURN @EXIT
END
```

El código actual es:

```
var codigo= new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "codigo",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value=0
};

var mensaje = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "mensaje",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value=""
};

var result =  _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.Login {0},{1},{2},{3}", usuario, password,codigo, mensaje);

int returnValue = (int)codigo.Value;
string returnValue2 = (string)mensaje.Value;
```

Para hacer esto seguí el siguiente tutorial:

[Tutorial](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/11/02/ef-core-sproc-return-value.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tus parametros en tu codigo C# deben llamarse igual a como estan en el procedimiento

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOGIN]
    @LOGIN    VARCHAR(50),  
    @PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
    @EXIT     INT OUTPUT,
    @MENSAJE VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
```

Cambia el valor de tu ***ParameterName*** de 'codigo' a 'EXIT'

```
var codigo= new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "EXIT",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value=0
};

var mensaje = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "MENSAJE",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    Value=""
};
```

Esta como referencia en el tutorial que pasaste

https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/08/03/ef-core-call-stored-procedures-out-parameters.html

Comment: Hola @Cmbuffa lo intente de esa forma, pero aun sigue sin funcionar. Gracias